# Mysql select row when year and month is seperated

Tags: mysql

I have this table

[image]

and this is my table specification

[image]

as you can see month and year is in different column

how do i select rows that minimum in year 2017 and month 3

```
select custcode, month, year from mytable
where month >=3 and year >=2017
```

if i use month >=3 and year >=2017
rows that has month 1 or 2  in 2018 will not be selected.

What query should i use so i can get  this result

[image]

Comment: Consider storing dates a single entity, e.g. 2017-11-01

Comment: And please don't post pictures of text. Instead see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from your_table
where year >= 2018 
   or (year = 2017 and month >= 3)
```

Comment: do you have more dynamic solution? because the transaction will be dynamic in the future and right now the transaction has 2020 transaction. 
so i can select from 2017 transaction until now